# create a method to looks for some values inside a text

Tags: python

I have this text:

```
Current Battery Service state:
  AC powered: true
  USB powered: false
  Wireless powered: false
  Max charging current: 1500000
  Max charging voltage: 5000000
  Charge counter: 0
  status: 2
  health: 2
  present: true
  level: 94
  scale: 100
  voltage: 8146
  temperature: 351
  technology: Li-ion
```

and want to create a method to get the value maybe for level or voltage, something like this
get_battery_status(property) and pass it "level" and it should return 94 in this case, or pass "temperature" and return 351 on python 3

Comment: store the whole thing into a dictionary as key:value and you can directly access it. That would be the best way to do it

Comment: What have you tried so far? See [ask].

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dictionary from the text file, something like:

```
d ={}
with open("text.txt") as f:
  for l in list(f)[1:]:
    key, value = l.split(":")
    d[key.strip()] = value.strip()
print(d)

def get_battery_status(k):
  return d[k]
    
print(get_battery_status('level'))
print(get_battery_status('Max charging voltage'))
```

---

Output:

```
{'AC powered': 'true', 'USB powered': 'false', 'Wireless powered': 'false', 'Max charging current': '1500000', 'Max charging voltage': '5000000', 'Charge counter': '0', 'status': '2', 'health': '2', 'present': 'true', 'level': '94', 'scale': '100', 'voltage': '8146', 'temperature': '351', 'technology': 'Li-ion'}
94
5000000
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/fcdef14bb5)

---

### Update:

> but I have the whole text inside a variable like this...

Based on your comment, you can use:

```
text = """Current Battery Service state:
  AC powered: true
  USB powered: false
  Wireless powered: false
  Max charging current: 1500000
  Max charging voltage: 5000000
  Charge counter: 0
  status: 2
  health: 2
  present: true
  level: 94
  scale: 100
  voltage: 8146
  temperature: 351
  technology: Li-ion"""

d = {}
for l in [l.strip() for l in text.split("\n")[1:]]:
  key, value = l.split(":")
  d[key.strip()] = value.strip()
print(d)
  
def get_battery_status(k):
  return d[k]

print(get_battery_status('level'))
print(get_battery_status('Max charging voltage'))
```

---

[Demo 2](https://trinket.io/python3/8913588ac0)

Comment: this is great, but I have the whole text inside a variable like this: 'Current Battery Service state:\n  AC powered: true\n  USB powered: false\n  Wireless powered: false\n  Max charging current: 1500000\n  Max charging voltage: 5000000\n  Charge counter: 0\n  status: 2\n  health: 2\n  present: true\n  level: 94\n  scale: 100\n  voltage: 8146\n  temperature: 351\n  technology: Li-ion', not inside a txt file, how can I adapt that?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer and give it 1+, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use regex for your situation just like so -

```
import re


def extract_level(text):
    pattern = 'level: (.*)'
    try:
        return re.findall(pattern, text)[0]
    except:
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = '''
    Current Battery Service state:
      AC powered: true
      USB powered: false
      Wireless powered: false
      Max charging current: 1500000
      Max charging voltage: 5000000
      Charge counter: 0
      status: 2
      health: 2
      present: true
      level: 94
      scale: 100
      voltage: 8146
      temperature: 351
      technology: Li-ion
    '''

    print(extract_level(text))
```